# Get Branch items using VSTS Git API C#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to download all contents from Git Branch using VSTS Git API. I have successfully downloaded item using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/get
 but It always pointing to master branch. I want to point to another branch.

I got the solution - by passing branch name in "versionDescriptor.version" parameter we can get the item from specific branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that there are optional parameters you can provide to the REST request:

> **versionDescriptor.version**      string Version string identifier
>   (name of tag/branch, SHA1 of commit)
>
> **versionDescriptor.versionType**          GitVersionType Version type
>   (branch, tag, or commit). Determines how Id is interpreted

Simply append the parameters `&versionDescriptor.versionType=branch&versionDescriptor.version=[name of the branch]`.